NPN BJT (PBHV8140Z) Incorrect Gain?
I'm simulating a BJT-based push-pull circuit used to drive a PFET as shown below in LTspice but the gain factor of PBHV8140Z (NPN) seems incorrect. I'm seeing 1.96uA into the base, while seeing 1.14mA into the collector, implying that the gain is ~581 which is outside of the gain range the datasheet has shown.

Simulation Schematic + Capture

PBHV8140Z Gain Curve
My questions are:

Is there any good explanation to this behaviour?
Is it typical to have a gain this high despite not being mentioned in the datasheet?
Can the collector current be significantly higher than base current times the gain factor?

FYI:
NPN: https://www.nexperia.com/product/PBHV8140Z
PNP: https://www.nexperia.com/product/PBHV9540Z

Where did you get the model from? What is BF in the model?

Your circuit conditions don't match the conditions of the plot in the datasheet.  Your VCE is around 70V in your circuit, not 10V.  The model has a low VAF (Early Voltage), which you can see in Figure 5 of the datasheet in the steep slope of the lines.  But also notice that the horizontal axis stops at 5V.  With those slopes, imagine how high the lines would get at 70V.

I imported the SPICE model under 'documentation' at your Nexperia link and ran a simulation with Ib=2uA, emitter grounded and Vce = 85V. Similar results. The collector current is suspiciously Vce-dependent.

Seems like the model is suspect.

The VAF given in the model is 22. Which is an unusually low value (unusually steep slope.) Looking at Figure 5. I find a typical value closer to about 30 ((5-1)/(1.21-1.08)=30.77) looking at the curve marked as 108. So perhaps it really is that bad in that regard. It is an unusual BJT in terms of its high-voltage rating and relatively high (also) maximum collector current.

@periblepsis Maybe. The model matches the datasheet value reasonably well at Ib = 32.2uA Vce = 10V for an Ic of 47.6mA (typical 50mA).  It's not really spec'd for linear operation with large Vce.

I was just addressing your testbed results. The applied Vbc is many times the VAF.

Interesting... I simulated the same circuit except with different Q9 (NPN) and got the same result where the gain factor is implied to be larger than what the datasheet specified. The some of different models I tried are:

2SC4102U3
2SCR567F3
BSS64A
2N5550

These models are all from LTspice's default library and still produced the "error" we saw with the Nexperia models, perhaps I_C's dependency on V_CE lies in the circuit?
Any thoughts or explanation on why we see this result on other BJTs as well?

Sounds like it's real. It's not leakage. I don't suppose it has much effect in a switching circuit anyway, since the two states of concern are zero current and saturated or close to saturated.

I wouldn't call it suspicious.  Looks to me like the model is operating in line with the datasheet.  I think @periblepsis hit the nail on the head.  Not only is the Early Voltage quite low, Figure 5 in the datasheet only goes up to 5V for VCE.  The circuit in the question has a VCE of 70V for Q9, so imagine how high those curves get out there.  Even less steep lines found in the other transistors mentioned will rise quite dramatically once you get that far out there.  I believe you're right that this transistor is meant for switching applications, which it's not doing in the original circuit.

@SteKulov "unexpected", to me anyhow.  The model shows hFE peaking at about 3,400 with 4uA of base current (with Vce = 500V).
